# Selenium: why would "send_keys(Keys.RETURN)" work when "click()" doesn't?

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, phantomjs

I have an element corresponding to a button (the Bing search button, to be precise) and it responds and works properly to:

```
button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

but when I try:

```
button.click()
```

it give me back "\'\'undefined\' is not an object". Can someone offer and explanation on this? If it is relevant, I'm using PhantomJS as the browser, and I DO have text entered into the search field.

I got the code to work perfectly on my Mac, but it won't run now on my Ubuntu server. That might be important.

What seems to be causing the problem is that when you enter text into the Bing search bar, the bar expands and the button is moved to the right a substantial amount. Still, why would the click method not work when sending the return key DOES work?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it might happen. 
Try:

1. Check selector! Maybe other elements have same class (for example),  but you use `find_element_by_class_name`, which forks for SINGLETON element. Check trace-back for more.
2. AJAX issues. Some web-sites uses a lot of JS and it takes time for request or even click is not working for some reasons.
3. Due to previous problem, try click on element with JavaScript. If it is possible, try `driver.execute_script()` method for it.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. My guess is that the button only responds when a script determines that there is input in the text field. Try to wait for a short time before sending the "submit" event.